# Exception na remoção do ultimo elemento da ArrayList

Tags: java, exceção, arraylist

Meu Problema:

Tenho uma ArrayList de um objeto que representa o número de linhas na minha JTable, da classe model.
pois bem, todos os outros métodos estão funcionando, perfeitamente, o problema é o remove() Não faço a menor ideia de porque tá dando Exception na hora de remover o ultimo elemento da ArrayList. Na remoção dos outros elemento funciona, exceto o ultimo, problema é o ultimo.

O exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6

O que eu não entendo, porque ele me informa que index fora, pois, e o index certo. Tentei de varias formas, index -1, e outras cambiaras na tentativa de tentar descobrir o motivo e nada, busquei na internet e nada também.

código do Model do Jtable:

```
public class DisciplineModelTabel extends AbstractTableModel implements IEModelTable<Discipline> {

    private ArrayList<Discipline> rows;
    private Queue<Discipline> listRemoved;
    private String[] columns = new String[]{"ID", "Disciplinas"};

    private static final int COL_ID = 0;
    private static final int COL_NAME = 1;

    /**
     * Construtor: espera um objeto do tipo Discipline para 
     * instanciar a lista das Disciplinas.
     * @param disciplines - lista das disciplinas.
     */
    public DisciplineModelTabel(ArrayList<Discipline> disciplines) {
        this.rows = new ArrayList<>(disciplines);
        listRemoved = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    /**
     * Método que remove o ultimo elemento a entradar na fila.
     */
    @Override
    public void undoLastRemoved() {
        if(!listRemoved.isEmpty()) {
            Discipline discipline = listRemoved.poll();
            addDiscipline(discipline);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Método adiciona o elemento retirado da Jtable
     * para guardar na fila de deletados, para recuperação.
     */
    @Override
    public void addLastRemoved(Discipline discipline){
        listRemoved.add(discipline);
    }

    /**
     * Método que limpa a fila.
     */
    @Override
    public void clearlistRemoved() {
        if(!listRemoved.isEmpty())
            listRemoved.clear();
    }

    /**
     * @return - True para fila cheia false para não.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isEmptyList() {
        return listRemoved.isEmpty();
    }

    /**
     * @return quantidade de linhas na tabela.
     */
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return this.rows.size();
    }

    /**
     * @return quantidade de colunas na tabela.
     */
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return this.columns.length;
    }

    /**
     * Método que retorna os valores das linhas e colunas da tabela.
     * Instancia um objeto do tipo Disciplina e busca os valores de seus
     * atributos
     * @param rowIndex - Index da linha para retorno do valor.
     * @param columnIndex - Index da coluna para retorno do valor.
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Discipline discipline = rows.get(rowIndex);

        if(columnIndex == COL_ID)
            return discipline.getId();
        else if (columnIndex == COL_NAME)
            return discipline.getName();

        return "";
    }

    /**
     * retorna o valor da linha selecionada da JTable
     * retornando-o em um objeto.
     * @param aValue - o item selecionado.
     * @param rowIndex - index da linha do item da Jtable
     * @param column - coluna do item selecionado.
     */
    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int column) {
        Discipline discipline = rows.get(rowIndex);

        if (column == COL_ID)
            discipline.setId((Integer) aValue);
        else if (column == COL_NAME)
            discipline.setName(aValue.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Método que retorna o nome da coluna.
     * @param columnIndex - o index da coluna
     * @return - o nome da coluna.
     */
    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return columns[columnIndex];
    }

    /**
     * Método que retorna o tipo da coluna.
     * @return o tipo da coluna.
     */
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex == COL_ID) {
            return Integer.class;
        }
        return String.class;
    }

    /**
     * Método que retonar o objeto de uma linha da JTable.
     * @param rowIndex - o index da linha selecionada.
     * @return O item (disciplina) da linha selecionada.
     */
    @Override
    public Discipline getDiscipline(int rowIndex) {
        return rows.get(rowIndex);
    }

    /**
     * Método que adiciona uma elemento a Jtable e
     * atualizá-a para mostrar o elemento nela.
     * @param discipline - A entidade disciplina adicionada.
     */
    @Override
    public void addDiscipline(Discipline discipline) {
        rows.add(discipline);
        int lastIndex = getRowCount() - 1;
        fireTableRowsInserted(lastIndex, lastIndex);

    }

    /**
     * Método que altera um item na Jtable e 
     * atualiza para mostrar a alteração na entidade.
     * @param rowIndex - o index da linha selecionada para alteração
     * @param marca - entidade que vai ser alterada.
     */
    @Override
    public void update(int rowIndex, Discipline marca) {
        rows.set(rowIndex, marca);
        fireTableRowsUpdated(rowIndex, rowIndex);
    }

    /**
     * Método que remove um item da JTable e também
     * atualizá-a removendo o item da JTable.
     * @param rowIndex - o index da linha do item que vai ser removido.
     */
    @Override
    public void remove(int rowIndex) {
        fireTableRowsDeleted(rowIndex, rowIndex);
        listRemoved.add(rows.get(rowIndex));
        rows.remove(rowIndex);      
    }

    @Override
    public String getArray() {
        String disciplines = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
            disciplines += "index " + i + " nome: " + rows.get(i).getName() + "\n";
        }
        return disciplines;
    }

    /**
     * Método que habilida a edição na célula selecionada
     * @param rowIndex - linha selecionada.
     * @param columnIndex - coluna selecionada
     * @return retorna se Verdadeiro a célula pode ser editada falso para não.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Evento que chama o para executar a lista de processos:

```
btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            glassPanel.start();
            queue.executeProcess();
            model.clearlistRemoved();
            Thread performer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    perform();
                }
            }, "Performer");
            performer.start();
            quit();
        }
    });
```

Estou utilizando o Pattern Commands para criar uma fila de processos e executar quando o botão **OK for pressionado.** (queues.executeProcess).

código do invoker:

```
public class RemoveDiscipline implements IECommand {
    ControllerDiscipline controller;
    private int id;

    public RemoveDiscipline(int id){
        controller = new ControllerDiscipline();
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        controller.removeDiscipline(id);
    }
}
```

código da queues de processo:

```
public class QueuesProcess {
    private Queue<IECommand> process;

    public QueuesProcess() {
        process = new LinkedList();
    }

    public void addProcess(IECommand process) {
        this.process.add(process);
    }

    public void removeProcess(IECommand process) {
        this.process.remove(process);
    }

    public void clearQueues() {
        this.process.clear();
    }

    public void executeProcess() {
        for(IECommand command : this.process)
            command.execute();

        process.clear();
    }
}
```

O problema dispara na linha do **rows.remove(rowIndex);**

Comment: A exceção ocorre porque você está tentando acessar um indice inválido do array. Onde o erro estoura? Se possivel, adicione um [mcve] para que seja possivel simular o problema.

Comment: `fireTableRowsDeleted(rowIndex, rowIndex);` deve ser chamado após remover o elemento da lista, e não antes como está no método `remove`

Comment: sim, sim, na verdade esqueci de voltar as "gambiarras" que eu tava tentando fazer para achar o problema...na verdade a sequencia que eu escrevi e assim:
adiciona a lista de removidos;
retira da arrayList
e atualiza a Jtable.

Comment: Onde o erro dispara? Poderia postar um [mcve] da sua tabela e do arraylist?

Comment: Adicione mais informaçõe não sei se isto ajuda, assim, eu criei uma fila de processos, com o Pattern command, quando terminar as alterações, assim que clicar em OK o evento chama a método da da classe da fila que vai executar todos os processo nela, a qual chama o remover da arrayList

Comment: Bom, seria interessante um exemplo simples da jtable que fosse executavel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, resolvi o problema com a troca da API de arrayList para Vector, ambos são bem similares e não impactou tanto no desempenho da aplicação, como usam a mesma interface os métodos tem a mesma assinatura então não alterei em nada... não sei o que houve como estou sem tempo, prazo para entrega do trabalho acabando, para procurar a resolução. obrigado pela ajuda